# tf Python API transform points

Tags: python, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The TF documentation mentions that there are methods to convert points from one frame to another.  I am currently using the python tf api.

I have a list of [x,y,z] points in the sensor frame and I want to transform these points into the map frame.

calling this

```
 (tran, rot) = self.tf_listener.lookupTransform('/body', '/map', rospy.Time(0.0))
```

gives a translation vector and a quaternion for the rotation. I am not really familiar with quaternions... but I heard they are hard...

Anyway Is there a method in the python api  to convert my vector of points to another frame?
I noticed in the c++ tf api there was a function called transformPoint. Is this what I need?

My other idea is to use the transformation.py module to convert the quaternions and the translation vector to a homogeneous transformation matrix and transform the vector of points manually. (by using the transformations.py module) http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/RotationMethods#transformations.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146111/tf-python-api-transform-points/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2014-03-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The python tf API has `transformPoint`, and `transformPointCloud`. I'm not sure why they don't show up in the API docs, but here's how they work:

```
transformPoint(self, target_frame, ps) method of tf.listener.TransformListener instance
    :param target_frame: the tf target frame, a string
    :param ps: the geometry_msgs.msg.PointStamped message
    :return: new geometry_msgs.msg.PointStamped message, in frame target_frame
    :raises: any of the exceptions that :meth:`~tf.Transformer.lookupTransform` can raise
    
    Transforms a geometry_msgs PointStamped message to frame target_frame, returns a new PointStamped message.


transformPointCloud(self, target_frame, point_cloud) method of tf.listener.TransformListener instance
    :param target_frame: the tf target frame, a string
    :param ps: the sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud message
    :return: new sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud message, in frame target_frame
    :raises: any of the exceptions that :meth:`~tf.Transformer.lookupTransform` can raise
    
    Transforms a geometry_msgs PoseStamped message to frame target_frame, returns a new PoseStamped message.
```

You'll have to either loop over your vector and create `PointStamped` objects, or pack all the points into a `PointCloud`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2014-03-30**:
Hi thanks I use the pointcloud method. I found some documentation here http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html.  But the official link is missing sections

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can transform points in base_link frame to odom frame using TF as follows

```
listener = tf.TransformListener()
listener.waitForTransform("/base_link", "/odom", rospy.Time(0),rospy.Duration(4.0))
laser_point=PointStamped()
laser_point.header.frame_id = "base_link"
laser_point.header.stamp =rospy.Time(0)
laser_point.point.x=1.0
laser_point.point.y=1.0
laser_point.point.z=0.0
p=listener.transformPoint("odom",laser_point)
```

Output look likes

```
[ INFO] [1498858767.555667233]: Current: [X= 0.105044,Y= -0.020144,Theta= -22.776758]

header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: odom
point: 
  x: 1.41420562607
  y: 0.514734522986
  z: 1.0
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2017-11-23**:
+1 for showing example